# Drupal isn't picking up my custom action

Tags: actions

I wrote a couple of actions for my Drupal page, but for some reason, Drupal isn't picking them up... Nevertheless, it's a copy/paste of the Drupal.org website...

```
   function publicatie_omgeving_action_info() {
      return array(
        'publicatie_omgeving_publish_action' => array(
          'type' => 'node', 
          'label' => t('A'), 
          'configurable' => FALSE, 
          'behavior' => array('changes_property'), 
          'triggers' => array('comment_presave', 'comment_insert', 'comment_update'),
        ), 
        '_mijn_organisatie' => array(
          'type' => 'user', 
          'label' => t('AA'), 
          'configurable' => TRUE, 
          'behavior' => array('changes_property'), 
          'triggers' => array('comment_presave', 'comment_insert', 'comment_update'),
        ), 
        'publicatie_omgeving_menu' => array(
          'type' => 'comment', 
          'label' => t('AAA'), 
          'configurable' => FALSE, 
          'triggers' => array('comment_insert', 'comment_update'),
        ),
      );
    }
```

I only get the first one, `A`. Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: cleared the cache and tried?

Comment: Yep, I did. Still, no result

Comment: where is this function documented? I checked google and found nothing. Is it meant to be overriding a drupal function or is it a custom function you made? Where is it being called?

Comment: It's the `hook_action_info`-hook...http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_action_info/7

Comment: Knowing Drupal it's probably a naming convention issue, try prefixing the second action key with the module name, i.e. `publicatie_omgeving_mijn_organisatie`

Comment: Nice guess, but unfortunately, I still see only `A`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that, by convention, an action function should start with modulename_ (to prevent namespace collisions) followed by a short description of what it does, eg publish, but in order to be found at all, it needs to end in _action.

So try naming all of your functions:

```
publicatie_omgeving _ SOMETHING _ action
```

and see what happens.